# AWS Amplify - How do I resend a confirmation code during sign up flow

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify

Just a quick question I don't seem to find an answer for on the internet.

When a user signs up for an account using **AWS Amplify for iOS**, I want the user to tap a button to trigger a resend confirmation code process.

I already use this for email confirmation, but I'm not sure how it is done when the user is just about to sign up for an account.

Amplify provides us with a handy API `Amplify.Auth.resendConfirmationCode(for: .email)`. This API, although it doesn't let me send a code for the username/sign-up flow.

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error when you call the resend API: Amplify.Auth.resendConfirmationCode ?

Comment: No error. But I'm not quite sure what attribute is being validated in the sign-up. Is it the username or the email?

Comment: Check if you have followed the guide correctly? https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin/q/platform/ios

Comment: So I tested this today, and while implementing a reset password process, where the user should be able to request a new code as well, this error came about: `Resend code failed with error AuthError: Could not resend attribute confirmation code, there is no user signed in to the Auth category
Recovery suggestion: SignIn to Auth category by using one of the sign in methods and then call user attributes apis`

Comment: I'm getting the same error during the sign up process. It seems you can only send a confirmation code if the user is already signed in. So how do you initiate a resend during the sign up process.

Answer (score 1):

I am implementing same feature at the moment and this is what I use.

- For reset password (on login screen, when user is not signed in):

```
Amplify.Auth.resetPassword(for: email, options: nil) { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error): 
                        // handle error here
                case .success(let resetResult):
                    switch resetResult.nextStep {
                    case .done: 
                        // handle success here
                    case .confirmResetPasswordWithCode(let details, let info):
                        // handle code confirmation here by calling confirmResetPassword
                    }
                }
            }
```

Then, to confirm new password with provided code:

```
Amplify.Auth.confirmResetPassword(for: email, with: newPassword, confirmationCode: receivedCode, options: nil) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    // handle success
                case .failure(let error):
                    // handle error
                }
            }
```

- In order, to ask for new signup confirmation code (eg. when app was interrupted):

```
Amplify.Auto.resendSignUpCode(for: email, options: nil) { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    // handle error
                case .success(let details):
                    // handle success for resending code, then confirm using usual flow with confirmSignUp
                }
            }
```

Error you posted in comments seem to be coming from case when user would like to update account details in eg. cognito but is not signed in (eg. user wants to change nickname)

Hope this helps..